# Why doesn't moveTo(0, 0); lineTo(X, X); draw a 45° line?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas, 2d

I spent a lot of time today trying to do some simple canvas work (which I haven't played with in quite a while), but lines weren't drawing to the right places. It turns out that it was JavaScript and/or Canvas that was screwy, not my math. Given a 2D canvas context, the following:

```
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(50, 50);
context.stroke();
```

…draws a line that seems to be at 30° or so, not 45° as expected. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6HaC/).

The only way that this makes sense is if the canvas/context is using non-square pixels… Is that really the case? Whose bright idea might that be? Is there a way to force the canvas to use square pixels instead to make my math easier?

Comment: Change 'not draw a right angle' to 'not draw a 45 degree angle'. Isosceles also doesn't mean what you seem to think it means. I have no idea why it's clearly [behaving badly](http://jsfiddle.net/t6HaC/10/) though, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough. It's been a while since I had any geometry classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're resizing the canvas with CSS.

Resizing in CSS **actually does** result in stretched drawings.

If you need to resize, this will not "stretch the pixels":

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width=500;
canvas.height=300;
```

Comment: I guess this almost makes sense if you think of `<canvas>` as working like `<img>`. Almost. Very strange behavior, though.

Answer (score 1):

markE has it entirely right. In your example, you've set up a canvas in the HTML which will have default dimensions of 300px by 150px. When you then set the dimensions via CSS, the canvas gets 'stretched' rather than resized. An alternative to markE's solution is to set up the canvas with explicit dimensions:

```
<canvas id="the-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Canvas can only take pixel sizes so suffixing with `px` won't (shouldn't) work. Only use a simple value as Garret sort of points out. (width="300" etc.).